# The EntitySet 'AspNetRoles' with schema 'dbo' and table 'AspNetRoles' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

error in migrations :

> PM> enable-migrations Checking if the context targets an existing
>   database...
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> AspNetRoles: Name: The EntitySet 'AspNetRoles' with schema 'dbo' and
>   table 'AspNetRoles' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to
>   a unique schema and table.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext
>   db)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String
>   nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String
>   nameOrConnectionString)    at Apk.Model.ApkEntities..ctor() in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Apk\Apk.Data\ApkEntities.cs:line 10
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String
>   language, String rootNamespace)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:
>
> AspNetRoles: Name: The EntitySet 'AspNetRoles' with schema 'dbo' and
>   table 'AspNetRoles' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to
>   a unique schema and table.

Why does this error occur?

I need to change in IdentityRole and IdentityUser.

```
 public class ApkEntities : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApkEntities ()
            : base("ApkEntities")
        {
        }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AspNetRoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AspNetUserConfiguration());
        }
    }



 public class AspNetRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public AspNetRoleConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
        {
            ToTable(schema + ".AspNetRoles");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
            Property(x => x.NameFa).HasColumnName("NameFa").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsOptional().HasMaxLength(250);
            Property(x => x.IsActivated).HasColumnName("IsActivated").IsRequired();
        }
    }

 public class AspNetUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AspNetUserConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
        {
            ToTable(schema + ".AspNetUsers");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            Property(x => x.Email).HasColumnName("Email").IsOptional().HasMaxLength(256);
            Property(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberConfirmed").IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName").IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName").IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated").IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash").IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp").IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        }
    }



     public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string NameFa { get; set; }
            public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
        }

     public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public ApplicationUser()
            {
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                LF_FavoraiteTeam = new Collection<LF_FavoraiteTeam>();
            }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
            public DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }
            public bool? IsActivated { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<LF_FavoraiteTeam> LF_FavoraiteTeam { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: The error says that your DB already has table `AspNetRoles` and your migration tries to create yet another one with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole DbSets explicitly in your ApkEntities context and remove the properties which are already in the IdentityRole and IdentityUser objects. The are already defined by inheriting from the IdentityDbContext.